# Full Calendar didn't work for me

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to integrate on my site the fullcalendar linked to google calendar.
I can show the full calendar on my site with the default events (all day event, etc)

I use the guide http://fullcalendar.io/docs/

The problem is when I try to integrate it with google calendar. I get the browser key and the ID calendar but it still showing the default events...

My code on the head is:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
    <script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                googleCalendarApiKey: 'MY_BROWSER_KEY',
                events: {
                    googleCalendarId: 'MY_CALENDAR_ID'
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

At the body I have the:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

I have follow the guide step by step. But as I said, the fullcalendar stills showing the defaults events and not the google calendar events.
[image of my fullcalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkp2H.png)

What I am doing wrong??

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean default events? There are some demo events in full calendar itself. Are you talkng about them?

Comment: I mean the demo events that have full calendar. I need to get the google calendar events instead of this 'demo' or 'default' events that comes with fullcalendar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stucked with this and I need to solve it.
I have tryed a lot of codes for getting the gcalendar events or integrate fullcalendar with google calendar but does not work.

I only need an example of one of this. Get the gcalendar events or the integration with fullcalendar with the keys.

I don't know what else to do..